# Using WMI to create active directory dns zones

Tags: c#, dns, wmi

I'm using the following code to create a DNS zone:

```
ManagementClass zoneObj = new ManagementClass(session, new ManagementPath("MicrosoftDNS_Zone"), null);
ManagementBaseObject inParams = zoneObj.GetMethodParameters("CreateZone");
inParams["ZoneName"] = "thedomain.com";
inParams["ZoneType"] = 0;
ManagementBaseObject outParams = zoneObj.InvokeMethod("CreateZone", inParams, null);
```

This creates the zone, but creates it with the type "Standard Primary". I need it to create with the type "Active Directory - Integrated Primary". From all my research, the zone type of "0" should do this. Can anyone tell me why it won't create the zone as an active directory zone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Anyone else with the same issue, you have to add the DsIntegrated parameter to tell it to use Active Directory. Here is the final code:

```
ManagementClass zoneObj = new ManagementClass(session, new ManagementPath("MicrosoftDNS_Zone"), null);
ManagementBaseObject inParams = zoneObj.GetMethodParameters("CreateZone");
inParams["ZoneName"] = "thedomain.com";
inParams["ZoneType"] = 0;
inParams["DsIntegrated"] = true; //--- this is what needed to be added
ManagementBaseObject outParams = zoneObj.InvokeMethod("CreateZone", inParams, null);
```

DsIntegrated
Indicates whether zone data is stored in the Active Directory or in files. If TRUE, the data is stored in the Active Directory; if FALSE, the data is stored in files.